# How to replace "-" with "_" and remove index.php from the address bar

Tags: .htaccess

I have developed my website in codeigniter. I have a couple of things to accomplish in .htaccess file.

- For any page/resource other than `index.php`, `img`, `js`, `css` i want it to add `index.php` before the actual resource in the url.
- I have so many static pages having unserscore "_" in them, e.g, `contact_us.php`, `our_services.php` etc. I want when user gives the url like `www.mywebsite.com/our-services`  it should open up the original page, that is, `www.mywebsite.com/our_services`. There are 1,2 upto 7 underscores for different pages, e.g, `mywebsite.com/speech_writing_services`

Here is my .htaccess file which i could build up so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/StyleAdmin|/images|/StyleAdmin/images|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4_$5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4_$5_$6 [R=301,L]
```

The problem here is that when i give the url like `www.mywebsite.com/contact_us` it works just fine and shows the same url in the address bar. But when i give this url `www.mywebsite.com/contact-us` it does show the page but the url shown in the address bar of the browser becomes `www.mywebsite.com/index.php/contact_us` whereas i want it to be like `www.mywebsite.com/contact_us` with `index.php` removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the routing after the redirecting.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4_$5 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1_$2_$3_$4_$5_$6 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/StyleAdmin|/images|/StyleAdmin/images|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```